# Push GCP PubSub events to Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, event-handling, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using GCP pub sub topics to store specific events in my applications and then have custom code running based on topic subscriptions fire to process db transactions calls to my database.  Aside from the subscriptions that storr records in my OLTP database I'd also like another subscriber for each topic to push the JSON object into Cloud datastore entities. What is the easiest way to do this?  Can I accomplish this without having to write custom code?

Answer (score 1):

The [Dataflow template for moving data from Pub/Sub to Datastore](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/main/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/PubsubToDatastore.java) may work for you. This SO question provides some tips on getting the template running: [Is it able to stream data from pubsub to datastore using dataflow？](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51926337/is-it-able-to-stream-data-from-pubsub-to-datastore-using-dataflow)